batch.jobs perform_in rather than perform_async
We had a situation where spawning 3000+ child jobs with perform_async inside a batch.jobs block caused all child jobs to "bunch up" and prevented other jobs from executing. The pseudo code looks like:
      batch.jobs do
        orders.each_batch do |order_batch|
          OrdersWorker.perform_async(order_batch)
        end
      end

We solved it by changing perform_async to perform_in:
      batch.jobs do
        orders.each_batch.each_with_index do |order_batch, index|
          OrdersWorker.perform_in(index * 5.seconds, order_batch)
        end
      end

Is this the correct approach? Or is there a more canonical solution?
Our solution changed all the child jobs into scheduled jobs and only moved them onto the queue when the scheduled time arrived. This allowed other standalone jobs to be enqueued and executed.
It solved our immediate problem, but I am not certain that this is the correct solution, and am looking for a better one if it exists.
We were on the Pro subscription when the above happened, and now we're on Enterprise. Will Enterprise's rate limiting help in this case?

Received a support email from Mike Perham confirming this is the correct approach.
